# Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and Improper Integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

---

$F'(x)=\frac{1}{x^n +4}$, where $n>1$.

Prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}F(x)$ exists.

---

So my thought went to use the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$F(x)=\int_a^xF'(t)dt=\int_a^x\frac{1}{t^n+4}dt$

Taking the limits to infinity of both sides...

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}F(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\int_a^x\frac{1}{t^n+4}dt$

And then I can't see whats next without doing something I'm unsure of.

My next thought involved if $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}F'(x)=0\Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}F(x)<\infty$; as that limit of F(x) would be a constant.  I've however found that to be easily disproven by playing with trig functions.

Any hints?  I still think the fact $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}F'(x)=0$ is something very useful here.

---

So how about this?
$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}F(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\int_a^x\frac{1}{t^n+4}dt=\int_a^\infty\frac{1}{t^n+4}<\int_a^\infty\frac{1}{t^n}dt=\int_a^\infty{t^{-n}}dt=\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}[\frac{t^{-n+1}}{-n+1}]|_a^b$

$=\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{(b^n-1)(1-n)}-\frac{1}{(a^n-1)(1-n)}=-\frac{1}{(a^n-1)(1-n)}$; noting of course that $n>1$.

At this point If I select some specific arbitrary $a$ I could show its finite by Improper Integral Comparison Test?

Comment: I would use the limit comparison test for improper integrals, comparing with $\int_a^\infty t^{-p}\,dt$.  Edit: Or in this particular case, just a straight comparison test would work.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, I added a short edit going through it to be sure.  Thank you for the reply!

Comment: It looks reasonable - though there is one minor error I didn't notice before.  The formula should actually be $F(x) = F(a) + \int_a^x F'(t)\,dt$.  It doesn't change the argument significantly, though, to carry through the $F(a) + \cdot$.

Answer (score 4):

For $n>1$ and enough great $t$, we have

$$0 <\frac {1}{t^n+1}<\frac {1}{t^n} $$

and
$\int^{+\infty}\frac {dt}{t^n} $ converges.

thus $\int^{+\infty}\frac {dt}{t^n+1} $ converges too. This means that
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\int_a^x\frac {dt}{t^n+1} $$ exists.